# Parameterize YAML file

Tags: python, parameter-passing, yaml

I am looking to parameterize the value of a variable - like http_proxy in the example below:

```
   parameters:
  - string:
      name: http_proxy
      default: 'http://myproxy.company.com'
```

I have two questions:

(1) how do I "parameterize" the default value (`'http://myproxy.company.com'`)?  I suppose it can be done like:

```
default: %proxy_url%
```

(2) if the above is correct, do I just set it up in a "properties" (or equivalent) file?  If so, how do I configure it to make my yaml file read in the proxy_url from the "properties" file?   thank you.

Comment: What is reading your YAML file?  YAML by itself can't magically be parameterized as you are describing, it all depends on what is processing the YAML.  If you're reading it with your own Python code, it would be your job to look for variables like `%proxy_url%` in the document and perform the appropriate substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain YAML, this is **not** possible.

You have the following options:

- Edit your YAML-parser to recognize the `%proxy_url%` and fill it
- Read the file, replace the `%proxy_url%` with your desired url and then give the result to the parser
- Use [YAMLs node anchors](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785586)

The first two solutions do work, and if you can't (or won't) save the `proxy_url` inside the YAML file, you can not get around these.

But **if** you can save it in the YAML file, use node anchors - because they are awesome!

I give you a very basic example:

```
defaults:
  proxy_url: &anchor_proxy_url http://myproxy.company.com
server:
  [... i don`t know how your file looks so just an example here]
  parameters:
   - string:
     name: http_proxy
     default: *anchor_proxy_url
```

Side note:
*If you want to use the `- string:` to indicate that the following entry is of kind `string`, i'll recommend you to use [YAML tags](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2784064) - because they are also awesome.*

Comment: Thank you Mijago.  I wonder if we can do this using shell scripting instead of python?  But I will post a new question and close this one.